# Function in function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a question.
I want to write (for example this) function (in R):

```
fun=function(x){
g=x[1]; z=x[2]; d=x[3]
fun=2g+1+3z*F(d)}
```

where F(d) is function of d.  After that I will use *optim* function for optimalization of parameters (g,z,d). How I do write this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `2*g+1+3*z*F(d)` is `fun`s result and that `F` is defined, you simply pass the initial parameters in `optim`

```
fun <- function(x){
  g<-x[1]; z<-x[2]; d<-x[3];
  2*g+1+3*z *F(d)
}

optim(c(1, 1, 1), fun)
```

Reference: [optim](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html)

Comment: @sgtFury don't forget to mark this question as helpful to thank the author, with the green sticky.